# Why is template specialization of variadic templates different from specialization of non-variadic templates?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates, specialization

I'm don't understand why template specialization is different for variadic templates than for regular (i.e., non-variadic) templates. For example I have a template and a specialization like:

```
enum class MF : int {
    ZERO = 0,
    ONE = 1,
    TWO = 2
};

// --------- Specialization -------------
template <MF mf>
class Stat{
public:
    Stat(std::string msg) {
        cout << "Generic Stat construtor: " << msg << endl;
    }
};

// --------- Template Specialization -------------
template<>
class Stat<MF::ONE>{
public:
    Stat(std::string msg) {
        cout << "Specialized Stat constructor: " << msg << endl;
    }
};
```

I have specialized with a specific value of the `MF` enumeration.

Now if I want to specialize a variadic template I can't specialize the variadic template parameters with a specific value of the `MF` enumeration (e.g., `MF::ONE`), I can only specialize with a type, (e.g. `MF`).

```
// --------- Variadic Template -------------
template<MF mf, typename... E>
class Var{
public:
    Var(std::string msg){
        cout << "Generic Var constructor: " << msg << endl;
    }

};

// --------- Variadic Template Specialization -------------
template<>
class Var<MF::TWO, MF>{
public:
    Var(std::string msg){
        cout << "Specialized Var constructor: " << msg << endl;
    }
};
```

I would like to specialize my variadic template for a specific `MF` value, but it doesn't appear that I can.

Is there some aspect of the language that I'm missing that would allow me to do what I want? Something along the lines of:

```
template<>
class Var<MF::TWO, MF::ONE>{
public:
    Var(std::string msg){
        cout << "Specialized Var constructor: " << msg << endl;
    }
};
```

Complete example can be found [here](http://ideone.com/tKaagi)

Comment: `but it doesn't appear that I can.` do you get an error or anything?

Comment: Is `MF::ONE` a `typename`?  Then, why do you expect to be able to pass it to a `typename...`?

Comment: `MF::ONE` is an enumerate value.

Comment: @Paranaix the code won't compile if I specialize like `class Var<MF::TWO, MF::ONE>`. I get this error `error: template argument for template type parameter must be a type class Var<MF::TWO, MF::ONE>{`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`template`s are not macros.  `typename...` does not mean "take any number of comma delimited strings".  `typename...` means "take 0 or more types".

`MF::ONE` is not a type.

Attempting to pass `MF::ONE` where the `template` expects `typename...` is an error, because the `template` is asking for a `typename` not a value.

You can write a `template class` that takes 0 or more `MF`s.  You can write one that takes zero or more types.  You cannot write a `template class` that takes 0 or more `MF`s or types.  C++ does not support that.

If you must pass values via type, there is `std::integral_constant< TYPE, VALUE >`, which is a type that wraps an integral constant value.

```
template<MF mf, typename... E>
class Var;
template<>
class Var<MF::TWO, std::integral_constant<MF, MF::ONE>>{
public:
  Var(std::string msg){
    cout << "Specialized Var constructor: " << msg << endl;
  }
};
```

you'd instantiate this by `Var<MF::TWO, std::integral_constant<MF, MF::ONE>>`.

You can create aliases:

```
template<MF mf> using MF_t=std::integral_constant<MF, mf>;
```

to make your code look nicer:

```
template<MF mf, typename... E>
class Var;
template<>
class Var<MF::TWO, MF_t<MF::ONE>>{
public:
  Var(std::string msg){
    cout << "Specialized Var constructor: " << msg << endl;
  }
};
int main() {
  Var<MF::TWO, MF_t<MF::ONE>> instance("hello");;
}
```

For metaprogramming purposes, sometimes it is a wise idea to write your templates as always taking types, and never taking constants, and when you need a constant stuff it into a type like above.  Then `template<class...>class X` will match any such template.

You can gain access to the value of a `std::integral_constant` with `::value` or by constructing it and converting it to a value of that type.  (In C++1y and many C++11 compilers, that conversion is `constexpr`).

So

```
 MF x = MF_t<MF::ONE>{};
 MF y = MF_t<MF::ONE>::value;
```

will set `x` and `y` to `MF::ONE`.  In both cases, the right hand side should be a compile time expression, so:

```
MF_t< MF_t<MF::ONE>{} >
```

is a valid type (if a silly written one) that is the same as `MF_t< MF::ONE >`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation **and** demonstration! This makes it work.

Answer (score 4):

If I understood you correctly, you want your variadic template to be parameterized with any number of `MF` values. Well, don't declare it like this :

```
template<MF mf, typename... E>
```

... which declares any number of *type parameters*, but like this :

```
template<MF mf, MF... moreMF>
```

... which declares any number of *non-type parameters of type `MF`*.

That is to say, explicit specialisation is no different for variadic templates, but you somehow forgot how to parameter in-between.

Comment: The first argument has to b of type `MF`, but the other template parameters do not have to be `MF`, but could be any of a number of different types. I just used `MF` because it was what I already had. Sorry for the confusion.